# Cannot Find Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently completing a very basic computer programming module and have been trying to write code to calculate the inductance of five frequencies. However, the JavaScript does not function when the calculate button is clicked. There is clearly an error in the code, but I cannot work out where?

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inductive Reactance Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- This program asks the user to enter an inductor value and 5 frequencies. It then calculates each of the inductive reactances. -->
    <form onreset="myfunction()" align="center">
        <!-- Start of Form -->
        <font face="Garamond">
            <h1 style="color:#900C3F">Inductive Reactance Calculator </h1>
            <p style="color:#92E367">Please enter the value of the inductor:</p>
            <input id="ind" value="0" //>

            <!-- Asks user for inductance -->
            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter Frequency 1:
                <input id="f1" value="0" //>
            </p>

            <!-- Asks user for frequency 1 -->
            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter Frequency 2:
                <input id="f2" value="0" //>
            </p>

            <!-- Asks user for frequency 2 -->
            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter Frequency 3:
                <input id="f3" value="0" //>
            </p>

            <!-- Asks user for frequency 3 -->
            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter Frequency 4:
                <input id="f4" value="0" //>
            </p>

            <!-- Asks user for frequency 4 -->
            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter Frequency 5:
                <input id="f5" value="0" //>
            </p>

            <!-- Asks user for frequency 5 -->
            <button id="Submit" type="button" onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>

            <!-- Shows button which activates the calculate() function -->
            <button id="Reset" type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

            <p style="color: #808080" id="message">The value of the inductive reactance will appear here after clicking Calculate</p>
            <!-- Message area -->
    </form>
    <!-- End of Form -->

    <script>
        function calculate() { //declares the function calculate() 
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "" + "<br>"; //clears the message area
            var IND = document.getElementById('ind').value; //declares a variable which holds the capacitance 
            var F1 = document.getElementById('f1').value; //declares a variable which holds frequency 1

            var F2 = document.getElementById('f2').value; //declares a variable which holds frequency 2
            var F3 = document.getElementById('f3').value; //declares a variable which holds frequency 3
            var F4 = document.getElementById('f4').value; //declares a variable which holds frequency 4 
            var F5 = document.getElementById('f5').value; //declares a variable which holds frequency 5

            var freq = [F1, F2, F3, F4, F5]; //declares a 1-dimensional array to hold the five frequencies 
            var XC = []; //declares an empty array to hold the calculated inductive reactances (XC) 
            const pi = 3.14159; //declares pi as a constant
            var i; //declares a variable to be used to index both the For loop and the array

            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //Sets up the For loop which stops when i gets to 5
                if ((f1 || f2 || f3 || f4 || f5) == 0) { //If F1 OR F2 OR F3 OR F4 OR F5 are zero then we will be dividing by zero (infinity error)
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Zero Frequencies are not permitted. Please reset the form.";
                    break; //breaks out of the For loop because of the infinity error }
                }

                XC[i] = 1 / (2 * pi * freq[i] * IND); //while looping each reactance is calculated for the appropriate array index (i)
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "Xc(" + (i + 1) + ")=" + XC[i] + "Hz <br> "; //concatenate message area
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding `||`.

Comment: You have syntax errors.

Comment: Comments are not supposed to describe what the language means.

Comment: Syntax error at `error)` and `<br>";`. Remove extraneous linebreaks

Comment: also `onclick="Calculate()"` is not calling `function calculate()` as I think you are intending

Comment: Test if an array holds a zero: `array.filter( elem => elem === 0 ).length`  (Or if you need a boolean: `!!array.filter( elem => elem === 0 ).length`)

Comment: You have declared variables as F1,F2 etc but using them as f1,f2 etc. Javascript is case sensitive. Also you defined your function as calculator() and using it as Calculator().

Comment: pleas check this : https://jsfiddle.net/g535r6fx/

Comment: Thank you all for your help regarding the syntax errors etc. This is now functioning. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo at your HTML for the button to calculate. `onclick="Calculate()` is not `onclick="calculate()"`.

You also misunderstood `||`.

To have only 4 numbers after the comma, you can use the `toFixed()` method on your `XC[i]` like this: `XC[i] = XC[i].toFixed(4)`.

```js
function calculate() { //declares the function calculate() 
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "" + "<br>"; //clears the message area
  var IND = document.getElementById('ind').value; //declares a variable which holds the capacitance 
  var F1 = document.getElementById('f1').value; //declares a variable which holds frequency 1

  var F2 = document.getElementById('f2').value; //declares a variable which holds frequency 2
  var F3 = document.getElementById('f3').value; //declares a variable which holds frequency 3
  var F4 = document.getElementById('f4').value; //declares a variable which holds frequency 4 
  var F5 = document.getElementById('f5').value; //declares a variable which holds frequency 5

  var freq = [F1, F2, F3, F4, F5]; //declares a 1-dimensional array to hold the five frequencies 
  var XC = []; //declares an empty array to hold the calculated inductive reactances (XC) 
  const pi = 3.14159; //declares pi as a constant
  var i; //declares a variable to be used to index both the For loop and the array

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //Sets up the For loop which stops when i gets to 5
    if (f1 == 0 || f2 == 0 || f3 == 0 || f4 == 0 || f5 == 0) { //If F1 OR F2 OR F3 OR F4 OR F5 are zero then we will be dividing by zero (infinity error)
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Zero Frequencies are not permitted. Please reset the form.";
      break; //breaks out of the For loop because of the infinity error }
    }

    XC[i] = 1 / (2 * pi * freq[i] * IND); //while looping each reactance is calculated for the appropriate array index (i)
    XC[i] = XC[i].toFixed(4);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "Xc(" + (i + 1) + ")=" + XC[i] + "Hz <br> "; //concatenate message area
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- This program asks the user to enter an inductor value and 5 frequencies. It then calculates each of the inductive reactances. -->
<form onreset="myfunction()" align="center">
  <!-- Start of Form -->
  <font face="Garamond">
    <h1 style="color:#900C3F">Inductive Reactance Calculator </h1>
    <p style="color:#92E367">Please enter the value of the inductor:</p>
    <input id="ind" value="0" //>

    <!-- Asks user for inductance -->
    <p style="color:#92E367">
      Please Enter Frequency 1:
      <input id="f1" value="0" //>
    </p>

    <!-- Asks user for frequency 1 -->
    <p style="color:#92E367">
      Please Enter Frequency 2:
      <input id="f2" value="0" //>
    </p>

    <!-- Asks user for frequency 2 -->
    <p style="color:#92E367">
      Please Enter Frequency 3:
      <input id="f3" value="0" //>
    </p>

    <!-- Asks user for frequency 3 -->
    <p style="color:#92E367">
      Please Enter Frequency 4:
      <input id="f4" value="0" //>
    </p>

    <!-- Asks user for frequency 4 -->
    <p style="color:#92E367">
      Please Enter Frequency 5:
      <input id="f5" value="0" //>
    </p>

    <!-- Asks user for frequency 5 -->
    <button id="Submit" type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

    <!-- Shows button which activates the calculate() function -->
    <button id="Reset" type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

    <p style="color: #808080" id="message">The value of the inductive reactance will appear here after clicking Calculate</p>
    <!-- Message area -->

    <!-- End of Form -->
```

Comment: Now that this is functioning the answers I am getting are to about 20 decimal places. Is there an easy way to limit this to say four decimal places?

Answer (score 0):

I have just removed your errors and replaced your message with [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) function

```js
function calculate() {
 document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "<br>";
 var ind = document.getElementById('ind').value;
 var f1 = document.getElementById('f1').value;

 var f2 = document.getElementById('f2').value;
 var f3 = document.getElementById('f3').value;
 var f4 = document.getElementById('f4').value;
 var f5 = document.getElementById('f5').value;

 var freq = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5];
 var xc = [];
 const pi = 3.14159;
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if ((f1 || f2 || f3 || f4 || f5) == 0) {
// can replace the condition with f1*f2*f3*f4*f5 == 0
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Zero Frequencies are not permitted. Please reset the form.";
   break;
  }

  xc[i] = 1 / (2 * pi * freq[i] * ind);
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += `xc(${(i + 1)})${xc[i]}Hz<br>`;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inductive Reactance Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- This program asks the user to enter an inductor value and 5 frequencies. It then calculates each of the inductive reactances. -->
    <form onreset="myfunction()" align="center">
        <!-- Start of Form -->
        <font face="Garamond">
            <h1 style="color:#900C3F">Inductive Reactance Calculator </h1>
            <p style="color:#92E367">Please enter the value of the inductor:</p>
            <input id="ind" value="0" //>

            <!-- Asks user for inductance -->
            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter Frequency 1:
                <input id="f1" value="0" //>
            </p>

            <!-- Asks user for frequency 1 -->
            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter Frequency 2:
                <input id="f2" value="0" //>
            </p>

            <!-- Asks user for frequency 2 -->
            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter Frequency 3:
                <input id="f3" value="0" //>
            </p>

            <!-- Asks user for frequency 3 -->
            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter Frequency 4:
                <input id="f4" value="0" //>
            </p>

            <!-- Asks user for frequency 4 -->
            <p style="color:#92E367">
                Please Enter Frequency 5:
                <input id="f5" value="0" //>
            </p>

            <!-- Asks user for frequency 5 -->
            <button id="Submit" type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>

            <!-- Shows button which activates the calculate() function -->
            <button id="Reset" type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

            <p style="color: #808080" id="message">The value of the inductive reactance will appear here after clicking Calculate</p>
            <!-- Message area -->
    </form>
    <!-- End of Form -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate method starts with capital 'C', whereas, when you reference it in your button you call it with a lowercase 'c'.

```
<button id="Submit" type="button" onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

Should be

```
<button id="Submit" type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
```

(alternatively, you could change the method name instead of the button event attribute - either works)